# Unit Test with spring-boot-starter-test and cassandra

Tags: unit-testing, cassandra, datastax, spring-boot-test

My spring boot web application uses Cassandra DB via the Datastax client and the connection occurs as follow:

```
public CassandraManager(@Autowired CassandraConfig cassandraConfig) {
  config = cassandraConfig;
  cluster = Cluster.builder()
      .addContactPoint(config.getHost())
      .build();
  session = cluster.connect(config.getKeyspace());
}
```

When I run my Unit Tests, the spring boot application tries to load the CassandraManager Bean and connect to the Cassandra DB which is not up for the Unit Test as I do not need it. I get the following error: `[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect)`

Is there a way to avoid loading this Cassandra Manager Bean to run my UT as they do not need to connect to the DB ? Is it a good practice to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below which worked for me assuming, you are using `spring-data-cassandra`

First we create another configuration class which will be used for the tests that does not need cassandra connection. It is required as we need to exlude the `CassandraDataAutoConfiguration` class. Ex:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class})
public class NoCassandraConfig {
}
```

Then we will use this configuration on our test(s). Ex:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = NoCassandraConfig.class)
public class UtilitiesTest {
/*  Lots of tests that does not need DB connection */
}
```

And there you go.